# Extracting substring in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, substring

Let's say I have three rows with value as

```
1 121/2808B|:6081
2 OD308B|:6081_1:
3 008312100001200|:6081_1
```

I want to display value only until `B` but want to exclude  everything after `B`. So as you can see in above data:

- from  `121/2808B|:6081` I want only `121/2808B`
- from `OD308B|:6081_1:` only `OD308B`
- from `008312100001200|:6081_1` only `008312100001200`.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: Have you tried some code? Please post your attempts, so that we can help you in improving it. Also, why only `008312100001200` in the third row? I see no `B` there

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `regexp_substr('<Your_string>','[^B]+')`

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('121/2808B|:6081', '[^B]+')
FROM
    DUAL;

REGEXP_S
--------
121/2808



SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('OD308B|:6081_1:', '[^B]+')
FROM
    DUAL;

REGEX
-----
OD308


SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('008312100001200.', '[^B]+')
FROM
    DUAL;

REGEXP_SUBSTR('0
----------------
008312100001200.
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e1ec4e190bf2a59011559d30ae6d6aa)

Cheers!!

Comment: This won't work for the 3rd sample data the OP posted, `008312100001200|:6081_1` as there's no `B` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using SUBSTR() and INSTR()

```
select   SUBSTR('121/2808B|:6081',1,INSTR('121/2808B|:6081','B', 1, 1) -1) 
from DUAL
```

Comment: This won't work for the 3rd sample data the OP posted, `008312100001200|:6081_1` as there's no `B` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to mention that you wanted to use `|` as a field separator, but I deduced this from the expected result from the third string. As such the following should give you what you want:

```
WITH cteData AS (SELECT 1 AS ID, '121/2808B|:6081' AS STRING FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2, 'OD308B|:6081_1:' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3, '008312100001200|:6081_1' FROM DUAL)
SELECT ID, STRING, SUBSTR(STRING, 1, CASE
                                       WHEN INSTR(STRING, 'B') = 0 THEN INSTR(STRING, '|')-1
                                       ELSE INSTR(STRING, 'B')-1
                                     END) AS UP_TO_B
  FROM cteData;
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=abb1b5af4048c88d9ff446b9ee37de5b)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Bob Jarvis is correct in the assumption that "|" is also a delimiter (as seems likely) try:

```
-- define test data
with test as
     ( select '121/2808B|:6081' stg     from dual union all
       select 'OD308B|:6081_1:'         from dual union all
       select '008312100001200|:6081_1' from dual
    ) 
-- execute extract
select regexp_substr(stg , '[^B|]+') val
  from test ;
```